# how to work with variable data structures and templates

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, sql-azure

I need users to be able to create an organization which will have some preset fields such as Name, Address, and Type. But depending on the type, the organization can have type-specific fields such as as President, Manager, or something that I can define at a later date that the user can also fill out about their organization. Basically, the type is the template for the organization data structure. How can I go about doing this? What sort of data structures would I need? I have looked into EAVs, xml, json, etc. But I am looking for advice on specifically Azure sql / sql-server db and the structures they allow.

Comment: How many custom fields are there?

Comment: it could be around 5 - 10.

Comment: Create label/pair fields in the database, as in FieldLabel1, FieldValue1.